# Why does a question appear as modified by the Community user

Tags: support, community-user, bump, posts

Why does a question appear as modified by the Community user, but when you click on it there's nothing in the question or its answers done by him/it ?

Comment: Aaargh! That Community user sticks its fingers everywhere!

Comment: Oh the irony; the accepted answer there is by the same user!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

kd304 describes the most likely reason for "Community ♦" getting involved. Just for completeness, there is another purpose that you ***don't*** want to see on your posts... it is "Community ♦" who gets the blame if your post is obliterated as spam/offensive. Of course, you'd probably need > 10k rep to *see* the remains of such a post...

Answer (score 6):

Community user is an automated process to stirr up some old and unanswered question. Actually, the user page belonging *on* the Community user describes its purpose.

Comment: ah, it bumped it?

Comment: You should be awarded a badge for meeting with the misterious stranger (F3 :)

Comment: As for that user page, for example: http://superuser.com/users/-1/community

Answer (score 3):

There's another reason for a question appearing to have been modified by the Community user - when a question is migrated, it's shown as edited by the Community user on the target site.

Answer (score 1):

When this is happening it is just the Community user making an "edit" (even though nothing is changed) to a random older post, to give it a bump (keeps the homepage fresh and helps questions that might have been missed get more attention).