# The Community User

Tags: discussion, community-user

What does the [`Community`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) user do?

In particular, the description says that one of the things that it does is

> Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention

What does that mean?

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By poking, it means bumping so it shows back up on the main screen just like an edit would.

This post has more information:
[Why does a question appear as modified by the Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6981/why-does-a-question-appear-as-modified-by-the-community-user)

Comment: Would a poke include removing then re-adding a tag?