# Migrated question popularity

Tags: discussion, migration

I've noticed that questions migrated from another site are answered less, and seem to never end up with an accepted answer.  This is partly because the person who started the question may not follow the question over to the other site.

This seems to make migrated questions far less appealing to answer than non-migrated ones.

Any idea how to make them more attractive?

Comment: I know I often feel discouraged by migrated questions especially if they're by a new user. That's unfortunate since they're usually the ones posting questions on the wrong site. I can try and answer the question but it's often like sending information into a black whole. I hope people find my post useful in the future but without feedback from the original poster I have no idea how effective my solution is. I've never had a question migrated so I'm not sure how the process is but maybe we need something to encourage people, especially the new users, to follow their questions to the next site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ask them on the right site in the first place.

Seriously, if we reset the question votes and cleared the comments, then they'd be treated like a real question (with bad tags), and get more play.

Comment: It's not generally myself asking questions.  Sure, people should ask them in the right place, but every day I see quite a few that are moved around.  I almost think a moderator should mark the question as "out of scope for this site, move to <wherever>", and then the original asking user needs to decide if they want to move it or let it die.  That way, the user asking the question has an active part of where it goes, and can track it -- and help answer givers earn those accepted answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm often fooled by the Community user as being the last to have changed the question. To me, that user makes migrated questions look just like old unanswered questions that have been randomly poked up to the front page (as to [get some attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6981/why-does-a-question-appear-as-modified-by-the-community-user/)). Too often, I find those poked question not very interesting because many of those have been abandoned by the question asker.

[image: Example of question poked onto the front page]

So: maybe for migrated questions the name of the original author (or whoever made the last change) can be used instead?

EDIT: Things [seem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899537/on-posting-outside-links-to-the-answer) to have changed:

[image: Migration message on Stack Overflow]

[image: Frontpage on Meta after migration, showing correct name]

Comment: That's odd. It shows up correctly authored in the new-questions list. I wonder why the active-questions list would act differently? But, good point. I tend to "ignore" Community questions, too.

Comment: Migrated 48 minutes ago: http://serverfault.com/questions/102459/role-with-owner-privilege which shows `48 min ago Community` on the activity page at http://serverfault.com/, but indeed shows `asked 1 hour ago sanjeev40084` on the newest questions at http://serverfault.com/questions?sort=newest So I guess the "asked" indicates that the latter page shows the authors (and when they asked the question), not whoever answered or edited last (and when they did that).

Comment: Those are not free hand circles

Comment: @Downvoter, I know, but I don't care. Well, I *do* care (and they're free hand alright), but not in the way *you* care. Now wishing this post was somehow locked... ;-) (Actually, I wish there were more scary monks like at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39782/javascript-tag-showing-up-as-javas-on-main-page)