# "Javascript" tag showing up as "javas" on main page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, homepage

This is one of the weirdest bugs I've ever seen, I think.

One of the tags on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287314/how-much-aggressive-could-one-go) is "javascript" but on the SO homepage, it shows up as "javas." If you click on it, that even takes you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javas (which has zero questions).

In the time it took me to write this up, the error seems to have been fixed (and that question closed) but I took a screenshot before that happened. It's the fourth question from the top.

[image: jawas on the main page]

Comment: Someone misspelled jawas.

Comment: Missing annotation in the form of freehand circles.

Comment: Those freehand circles get scarier every day ;-)

Comment: Those jawas aren't missing!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The snapshot cache of the front page was made before any subsequent edits during [the five minute grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9090/is-there-an-editing-grace-period-on-answers-after-they-have-been-posted).

As such, when they went to fix up the tag, it looked okay on the question page itself, but not on the home page, which is [lagging because it's cached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/853/how-aggressive-is-the-caching-used).

Comment: Obligatory: [shouldiblamecaching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)