# Don't show the community user as approving/rejecting an edit

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, community-user

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Improved edit suggestions approved by Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80518/improved-edit-suggestions-approved-by-community)

If you hit the improve button on a suggested edit, the suggested edit is handled in a very curious and surprising way: The user that is shown to have approved or rejected the suggested edit is the community user, instead of the user who actually clicked on the improve button.

This is wildly confusing to users, especially when their edits are getting rejected by the community user. Most users interpret this as an automated feature rejecting edits, some as community finally becoming self-aware and ready to begin it's war on humans. It's not widely known that an edit rejected by community means a user improved the edit and unchecked the "this edit was helpful" checkbox.

The suggested edit should clearly indicate who approved or denied the edit when they use the improve option and not put community as a scapegoat on the edit. This only serves to confuse users.

Comment: Note that *some* of the confusion [might be caused by edit clashes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124141/is-there-a-way-to-suggest-a-decision-by-the-community-bot-may-be-wrong/124146#124146), in which the (next) editor was oblivious about any pending edit, and did *not* reject/improve anything at all.

Comment: @Arjan If an edit clash with a 2k user rejects a suggested edit, I'd consider that behaviour wrong. Rejecting an edit can ban the user from suggesting more edits, so that shouldn't happen without someone actually looking at the edit

Comment: Very true, @Fabian, I couldn't agree more (though I'm not sure if this also counts as a rejection, or is only displayed as such). There's [an old bug report for that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88186/collision-detection-fails-when-saving-while-suggested-edits-are-pending); I just figured I'd mention it here to ensure folks know that not all approvals/rejections by Community are caused by "improve".